# Finding complex Fourier series of $f(x) = x$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f(x) = x , \ \ 0\le x \lt 2$ and $f(x+2) = f(x)$. Find complex Fourier series of $f(x)$.

If we compute $c_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{L}e^{-inx2\pi/L}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{2}0.5e^{-inx\pi}xdx = \frac{2i\pi n}{\pi^2n^2}$ but if we integrate in other interval with length $2$, we got different answer. For example $\int_{-1}^{1}0.5e^{-inx\pi}xdx = \frac{2i\pi n(-1)^n}{\pi^2n^2}$ which differs from $c_n$ by a factor $(-1)^n$. Why this happens? Integrating over any interval with the length of period should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\int_a^{a+2} f(x) dx$ is same for all $a$ but you cannot always substitute $x$ for $f(x)$ in this integral. For example when $x$ is between $-1$ and $0$ we have $f(x) =x+2$.

In your computation of $c_n$ you wrote $f(x)=x$ for $x$ between $-1 $ and $1$. That is not correct.

The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x-2n$ if $2n \leq n <2n+1$, $n$ varying over all integers.

Comment: So we can't use any interval with length of period for Fourier series?

Comment: @S.H.W You can use any interval of length $2$ but you cannot replace $f(x)$ by $x$.

Comment: Could you explain more, please? I'm still confused about that.

Comment: @S.H.W I have added the precise formula for $f(x)$ in each of the  intervals $[2n\2n+1)$. These intervals exhaust the entire real line.

Comment: What is the right answer, then?

Comment: @S.H.W The value you got when you integrated over $(0,2)$ is the correct value.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Fourier series for the Saw-tooth function:$$f(x)=x,~ 0\le x \le 2~~~~(1)$$
Also $f(x)$ is periodic with a period of 2 such that $f(x+2)=f(x), \forall x \in R$
The complex Fourier series representation of $f(x)=x$ is  written as
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{-N}^{N} C_n ~e^{i n\pi x}~~~~(2),$$
where
$$C_n=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2} x e^{-in\pi x} dx=-e^{-2in\pi}~\frac{-1+e^{2in\pi}-2in\pi}{2n^2\pi^2}=\frac{i}{n \pi} ~~~~(3)$$ 
$C_0$ takes the limiting value of 1. In the Fig. below see the plot of (1) amd (3)
by taking $N=20$ and using (3). See a good agreement expecting at the end points.

[image]